# Highcharts reversed line chart is partially hidden at min value

Tags: highcharts

When using a reversed line chart with min and max values, the line is partially hidden at the min value. The problem is that the drawing canvas ends exactly at the min value line. When you have a line that is thick only part of it is visible there, the part that is lying above the min value line is hidden. You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DruGa/2/). I tried different options to fix this but havent been successful. Is there a way you can increase the chart canvas on top?

This is the highcharts code:

```
$("#chart").highcharts({
  chart: {
  type: "line",
  spacingBottom: 30,
  height: 400,
  alignTicks: false,
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  title: {
    text: "Chart"
  },
  yAxis: [{
    title: null,
    reversed: true,
    showFirstLabel: true,
    allowDecimals: false,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    tickInterval: 5,
    minorTickInterval: 1,
    max: 10,
    min: 1,
  }],
  series: [{
    yAxis: 0,
    data: [6,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
    lineWidth: 10, 
    marker: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }]
});
```

Comment: Does your min need to be exactly 1?  Just set the min to 0.9 and all is well:  http://jsfiddle.net/DruGa/4/

Comment: Thanks, thats good enough as a workaround. Would be nice though, if there was an option to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min: 0.9` works well unless you have `tickPositions` set as well without `startOnTick` set. If you are setting `tickPositions`, then look at adding `startOnTick: false` to the yAxis as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is a problem - you have set strict `min` value for yAxis, so chart is forced to cut off that line, remove that option, and this will work perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/DruGa/5/

Comment: I have set a min value because I dont want that values below min should be included in the chart. But I want the chart to be diplayed perfectly when I use values in between min and max. That is not the case, so there is the problem.

Comment: Min option has higher priority than lineWidth. Workaround provided by Mark is good solution.