# Highcharts with a thick line - at 0 values the line is half hidden

Tags: highcharts

When the line is horizontal at `0` the part of the line that is out of bounds doesn't render. It only happens if all values are either `>= 0` or `<= 0`. If the values are both above and below `0` then the chart line renders nicely.

It's not a problem of the canvas cutting off, cause the dots/markers at each point still show fully.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/gxzo5wjn/3/

[image]

Can I tell the chart to start at `0.1`?

```
Highcharts.chart("chart", {
  chart: {
    type: "line",
    height: 300
  },
  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: "Hours per day"
    }
  }],
  series: [{
    data: [0,0,0,-2,-2,-1,0,-2],
    lineWidth: 8
  }]
});
```

If I change the data to add a `1` then the top value on the axis changes to `2` and the line isn't cut off.

Much the same as this question: [Highcharts reversed line chart is partially hidden at min value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047958/highcharts-reversed-line-chart-is-partially-hidden-at-min-value) but the answers there (to do with `min`) don't apply here, though maybe something combined with `startOnTick` will solve it.

Comment: Hi @Redzarf, You can set `yAxis.max` to `0.1` and disable `endOnTick` property, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qg6e97fz/

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek, that worked for me for negative values. Any idea for positive values? i.e. with data `[0,0,0,2,2,1,0,2]` - I tried `min: -0.1`, but that started the graph at `-1` instead of `0`.

Comment: You probably forgot to disable `startOnTick` property: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fed0tvwr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data like `[0,0,0,-2,-2,-1,0,-2]` use:

```
  yAxis: [{
    endOnTick: false,
    max: 0.1,
    ...
  }]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qg6e97fz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.endOnTick

---

For data like `[0,0,0,2,2,1,0,2]` use:

```
  yAxis: [{
    startOnTick: false,
    min: -0.1,
    ...
  }]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fed0tvwr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.startOnTick